# linearly dependent eigenvectors for a different eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I can't seem to find a straightforward answer anywhere. Can eigenvectors of different eigenvalues be linearly dependent?

Comment: Straight answer: no.

Comment: @GitGud thank you, that was all I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eigenvectors associated to different eigenvalues are *always* linearly independent

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Let $v_1 , v_2$ be eigenvectors and suppose $v_1=$ $\lambda$$ v_2$

$f(v_1)=$$\lambda_1 v_1 $=$\lambda$$f(v_2$)=$\lambda$ $ $$\lambda_2$ $v_2$=$\lambda_2$ $ $ $v_1$